# Locker service and document.createAttribute("XYZ")

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

When using LockerService in a Lightning community, I run this:

```
document.createAttribute("data-xyz");
```

The result when LockerService is activated is `null` instead of the attribute object.

I am pretty sure this is a regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a regression from the previous release, but it still should be fixed. I filed bug number **W-3736561** to track and added it to the queue of work items. I'll update this post as progress is made.

Comment: any news? I can still reproduce on spring 17.